# Is this a specific logic function?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I mean it this fits a logic function or its the way its reduced only.
This is the truth table
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & B & C & V\\ \hline 
\hline 
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ \hline
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ \hline
\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
\hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ \hline
\hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
\hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ \hline
\hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline 
\hline 
\end{array}

$$ABC+\bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C}$$

I was thinking of an XNOR of 3 inputs , but it is not.
The Karnaugh map suggest thats the minimal expression.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
 & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10\\ \hline
\hline 
\hline 
0 & x &  &  & \\ \hline
\hline 
1 &  &  & x & \\ \hline
\hline 
\end{array}

Comment: `A'B'C'` can be reduced (gate-wise) into `(A+B+C)'`

Comment: there's only a few rules in logic. learn them.. distribution et al

Comment: It is minimal.  There is no specific chip.  XORs and XNORs are outside the boolean rules.  You have to recognize the patterns from the KMAPs.

Comment: Perhaps the "all or nothing" logic function? I guess I don't know what you are looking for, really.